# Next js cannot find favicon in public folder

Tags: next.js

I changed a little bit of the setup of my `next.js` project, and now it cannot find `favicon.ico` in public folder.
My setup

[image]

in `pages/_app.js`

```js
import "styles/globals.css";
import Head from "next/head";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  console.log("My app");
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" /> //doesnt find
      </Head>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

but also I have `jsconfig.json` (I don't know if it has something to do with it)

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "baseUrl": "./src"
 }
}
```

When I enter to `localhost:3000/images/favicon.ico` my icon is there.

Comment: This specific icon issue has infuriated me before too. I solved it by moving it outside of images and having it only in public, and saving it as a png instead of ico. then referencing that. Maybe not ideal, but it worked for me a few times. But I'm really annoyed with this issue and haven't been able to figure out what the deal is, even with lots of stack overflow searching

Comment: For me it worked with default setup, when package.json and all other files where in the same directory as _app.js.

Comment: Nevermind, it was fine, just need to Forse refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned, I would do a **hard refresh (ctrl + shift + r)** on the page. I have encountered similar issues in a vanilla JS project (with Vite) and this solves the issue.

For whatever reason, it can pick up the favicon right away without a hard refresh if you reference the full file path directly (e.g., '/public/favicon.io') but the webpage has issues picking up just 'favicon.io' right away sometimes (even though that is the whole point of the public folder - those files are served at the root path).

- Example from my code: `<link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/public/favicon.ico" />`
- Terminal message: `files in the public directory are served at the root path. Instead of /public/favicon.ico, use /favicon.ico.`